# Running macros at scheduled time when pc is locked

Tags: excel, scheduled-tasks, vba

Background: Windows 7, Office 2010

I currently have 2 macros running by buttons, one macro calculates and extracts data and the other macro selects a specific range and sends an email to a specified email.

May I know how I can get this 2 macros to run at a scheduled time when my pc is locked - i.e. (on 'switch user' screen)?

Thank you and I sincerely appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: Task scheduler should be able to do this even if the user is not logged in...   have you set up a task and it's not running?

Comment: Sorry I am new to this, and I have no idea how to start. I tried searching online and got answers to creating a vbs script and saving excel as xls but I can't seem to do that in excel 2010. May I know how I can start working on it?

Comment: You could start by googling task scheduler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sub tempo()
    tps = Now + TimeValue("00:01:00") 'your refresh rate
    Application.OnTime tps, "message_ctrl"
End Sub

Sub message_ctrl()
     Call Module1.test  'your macro
     Call tempo 'this just relaunch schedule when test() finished
End Sub
```

Here exemple to refresh every minutes, but you can define day or anything.
You need to start once tempo() or message_ctrl() to start cycle. Maybe at workbook_open.
The key here is the **Application.OnTime** function.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: If it's okay for you, accept answer to close topic ;o)