# Run macro from Excel while screen is locked

Tags: excel, powershell, scheduled-tasks, lockscreen

I have programmed a macro that will update some excel files automatically and would like it to run when another other script downloads some data files from the internet.

However, I don't have sufficient privileges to check the "Run whether user is logged on or not".

Also, when the screen is locked, Task Scheduler can't seem to open the Excel file that has the macro which runs on file open.

I have browsed quite a few sites and can't really find any satisfactory answer. I would have used the powershell script which moves the mouse one pixel every 9.5 minutes to prevent it from sleeping if it didn't constitute a security risk. I imagine I could use a script that creates an artificial lock screen, locks the keyboard and mouse, while keeping everything alive so it can run the macro and the other powershell scripts, but I don't really have the expertise to do this.

Any other suggestions on how I can get around this? All answers much appreciated!

I really don't understand the answer at [Running macros at scheduled time when pc is locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624869/running-macros-at-scheduled-time-when-pc-is-locked)

Comment: Is having the Excel file permanently open an option? The answer you've referenced essentially runs `Module1.test` every minute. `tempo()` calls `message_ctrl()` at set times, which then calls `Module1.test`, then `tempo()` which calls `message+ctrl()` etc. As mentioned there, check out [Application.OnTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196165.aspx). 

Most likely you will need to have PowerShell and Excel communicate in some way - using an intermediate file if user restrictions stop you from doing it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it sounds like this problem:

> I can't check the "Run whether use is logged on or not" because I
>   don't have enough privileges

...is due to you not having admin privileges on the machine you're trying to create the scheduled task on. If you are an admin, run Task Manager as an admin, or run as a user with admin privs.

Assuming you meet the admin privs criteria, you could open the Excel workbook(s) and execute the macro using PowerShell. Create and save a PowerShell script with the code below. Amend to suit your workbook path, function name and params. Then create a scheduled task to call the PowerShell script.

What you will also need to to is to ensure the location of the Excel workbook is in a "trusted location". In Excel, go to File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Trusted Locations. If the folder containing your Excel workbook isn't there, click on Add New Location to add the folder.

If Add New Location is greyed out, this is most likely to a group policy set by your company (if you're on a company machine/domain). If so and there are some trusted locations, move your Excel workbook into one.

```
# set params for workbook
$WorkbookPath  = 'C:\Path\To\WEorkbook.xlsb'
$FunctionName  = 'HelloWorld'
$FunctionParam = 'Test'

# create an Excel com object
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.visible = $false

$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($WorkbookPath)

# call function with params. add extra comma delimited params here, like this:
# $Excel.Run($FunctionName, $P1, $P2, $P3, $P4)
$Excel.Run($FunctionName, $FunctionParam)

# close the workbook
$Workbook.Close()

# quit Excel and cleanup
$Excel.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel) | Out-Null
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```